# how to check the Markov property for a process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$(Y_n)_{n\in\{1,2..\}}$ is a i.i.d sequence f random variables.

$Y_1= 1$ with probability p and $Y_1=-k$ with probability $1-p$, where $0\leq p\leq 1$.

The process $(X_n)_n$ is defined as $X_0=0$ and $X_{n+1}=\max(X_n+Y_{n+1},0)$.

I have to prove that the process $(X_n)_n$ is an irreducibile Markov chain and I have to compute the matrix of the transition matrix P.

I'm tring to prove that $P(X_n+1=y |X_n=x,X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},..,X_1=x_1)$ does not depend on n but I am not able to conclude.

Any help ? Any hint to calculate P?

Comment: The Markov property follows from the definition of $X_{n+1}$. But I am not sure that $P(X_{n+1}=y|\cdots)$ is independent of $n$. For one thing $X_1\le1$ but $X_2$ can be equal to $2$. Note that not all Markov chains are stationary.

Comment: Ok !And have you any hint to calculate P ?

Comment: If $X_n \geq k$, then $X_{n+1}=X_n+1$ with probability $p$ and $X_{n+1}=X_n-k$ with probability $1-p$. Otherwise $X_{n+1}=X_n+1$ with probability $p$ and $X_{n+1}=0$ with probability $1-p$. I have just given a full description of the transition matrix; it remains only to organize this information into matrix form.

Comment: What @Ian said. And the chain is quite stationary.

Comment: and to have a statonary  process how I have to choose k and p ?